# how to let `clear` command just clears the current screen

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, iterm, zsh

I use iTerm2 apps as my terminal option on my Mac computers.

On my 1st Mac, when I type `clear`, it just clears out the current screen, and when I scroll up, it could still show the previous contents on this tab which I really like.

On my 2nd Mac, however, when I type `clear`, it clears everything out of this tab. When I try to scroll up, there's nothing’s present.

How can I make my 2nd Mac behave the same as my 1st one?

I've checked every single configuration in between these two machines for iTerm and they look identical, both are using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Check the Scrollback settings in both ITerms.  It’s probably set to 0 on the new Mac.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot Allan! To be more specific, it's in Preferences of iTerm -> Advanced -> search for Scrollback -> change it to either unspecified or yes. Please feel free to put this as an answer to this OP and I'll accept it for all future references. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Check iTerm2’s Scrollback Setting

The `clear` function just “cleans the terminal screen” so to speak.  The scrollback history is a function of the Terminal emulator (App) itself, not the shell (Bash/Zsh).

Go into *Preferences -> Profiles → Advanced → Scrollback Buffer* then set to either “unspecified” or “yes” (confirmed per the OP)

[image: iTerm 2 Profile Terminal Tab]

See [iTerm2 Terminal Profile Preferences Documentation](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html)

Comment: It works. Thanks